# I need to use variables defined in python within the latex document

Tags: python, latex

I'm not good in English, so, I'm sorry if I write something wrong.

I'm creating a program in python that receives a file with the inscriptions and returns a .pdf file with the championship brackets.

The program in python is working fine, but now I have to draw the brackets as [the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv4RR.jpg).

So, I have the "drawing" of the bracket done ([here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKr4Q.png)), now I need to complete it with the names of the competitors.

My program in python gives me a array with the name of the competitors for each category, so I need to define variables in my latex document that will be filed by the array that I have from my program.

For example, my program says that the name of the first competitor is Vivian Horing, so I need to put it in from of the number 1 in the bracket. How can I do this?

-----------------------------I already resolve this part (I put the answer in the final)----------------------------

I thought of making this image in latex, writing it's code within the python script, but if anyone has a better solution I'm ready to take it.

My problem is that I can't make the drawings where I want on the page. Trying to make the first square in the image (the one with a one inside), I'm trying this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (2mm,3mm) rectangle (10mm,10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I can't change where the square is on the page. I tried to change the (2mm,3mm) for a many different numbers, but nothings seem to change. And it seems that the (10mm,10mm) is the size of the rectangle.

I need to know how to draw all the other lines too.

This is the page of one category; I need to make it for all of the categories, so I need to use a variable for each name so that I can put this LaTex code in a loop, and then create the bracket for all the categories.

I googled a lot to find an answer to my problem, but I can't find anything to help me.

Thanks a lot to anyone who tries to help me.

-----------------------I've resolved the problem of the bracket drawing using the following latex script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{5mm}
  \begin{picture}(500,42)
    \linethickness{1pt}
    \put(4.4,39.2){\line(1,0){50}}
    \put(49,39.7){\makebox(0,0){C\'odigo}}
    \put(49,38.6){\makebox(0,0){Tatame}}
    \put(49,37.4){\makebox(0,0){In\'icio}}
    \put(49,36.2){\makebox(0,0){Premia\c c\H ao}}
    \put(49,35.0){\makebox(0,0){Atletas}}
    %linhas do desenho
    %linhas da primeira coluna
    \multiput(4.4,38.2)(0,-2){16}{\line(1,0){12.5}}
    %linhas da segunda coluna
    \multiput(16.9,37.2)(0,-4){8}{\line(1,0){12.5}}
    %linhas da terceira coluna
    \multiput(29.4,35.2)(0,-8){4}{\line(1,0){12.5}}
    %linhas da quarta coluna
    \multiput(41.9,31.2)(0,-16){2}{\line(1,0){12.5}}
    \put(48.2,30.7){\makebox(0,0){vencedor de A}}
    \put(48.2,14.7){\makebox(0,0){vencedor de B}}
    %linhas verticais primeira coluna
    \multiput(16.9,36.2)(0,-4){8}{\line(0,1){2}}
    %linhas verticais segunda coluna
    \multiput(29.4,33.2)(0,-8){4}{\line(0,1){4}}
    %linhas verticais terceira coluna
    \multiput(41.9,27.2)(0,-16){2}{\line(0,1){8}}
    %Numeros da primeira coluna
    \put(4.9,38.5){\makebox(0,0){1}}
    \put(4.9,36.5){\makebox(0,0){2}}
    \put(4.9,34.5){\makebox(0,0){3}}
    \put(4.9,32.5){\makebox(0,0){4}}
    \put(4.9,30.5){\makebox(0,0){5}}
    \put(4.9,28.5){\makebox(0,0){6}}
    \put(4.9,26.5){\makebox(0,0){7}}
    \put(4.9,24.5){\makebox(0,0){8}}
    \put(4.9,22.5){\makebox(0,0){9}}
    \put(4.9,20.5){\makebox(0,0){10}}
    \put(4.9,18.5){\makebox(0,0){11}}
    \put(4.9,16.5){\makebox(0,0){12}}
    \put(4.9,14.5){\makebox(0,0){13}}
    \put(4.9,12.5){\makebox(0,0){14}}
    \put(4.9,10.5){\makebox(0,0){15}}
    \put(4.9,8.5){\makebox(0,0){16}}
    %Complementos finais
    \put(4.4,6.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(11,5.7){\makebox(0,0){Chefe de Quadra}}
    \put(4.4,3.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(11,2.7){\makebox(0,0){Mes\'ario}}
    \put(26.5,7.2){\makebox(0,0){Atletas}}
    \put(19.8,6.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(19.8,5.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(19.8,4.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(19.8,3.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(35.3,7.2){\makebox(0,0){Classifica\c c\H ao}}
    \put(35.3,6.2){\makebox(0,0){1º}}
    \put(35.3,5.2){\makebox(0,0){2º}}
    \put(35.3,4.2){\makebox(0,0){3º}}
    \put(35.3,3.2){\makebox(0,0){4º}}
    \put(44,7.2){\makebox(0,0){Entidades}}
    \put(37.3,6.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(37.3,5.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(37.3,4.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
    \put(37.3,3.2){\line(1,0){13.5}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %quadrados da primeira coluna
    \multiput(4.4,38.2)(0,-2){16}{\draw(0,0)rectangle(0.5,0.5);}
    %quadrados da segunda coluna
    \multiput(16.9,37.2)(0,-4){8}{\draw(0,0)rectangle(0.5,0.5);}
    %quadrados do cabeçalho
    \multiput(51,39.3)(0,-1.2){5}{\draw(0,0)rectangle(1.5,0.5);}
    %\put(52,39.5){\draw(0,0)rectangle(1.5,0.5);}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need the brackets exactly as the image attached, it is a official bracket to karate's championship, and I need to keep it in the exactly same format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this answer on google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/wpVvnUG64uk) to see how to handle this?

In my opinion, combining python and LaTeX in this way is not the answer. A better option is likely this [dedicated python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BracketMaker/0.2.0) that does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: The python package doesn't work for me, because I need to create a .pdf of the bracket with only the competitors. I'm doing this program to make karate's championships, and they print this brackets to use during the confronts, and as it happens, they write the winner of the confront and so on.
The answer on google may help me, but just copying it and running is returning some errors. I'll try to understand it. Thank you!!